# How to list/show all custom post types regardless of category?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I realise with [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173797/can-we-have-a-php-page-without-a-wordpress-page) I was overcomplicating a really simple issue.

My question is really this:

How to have a page listing all items of a given custom post type?

Say the custom post type is **foobar**, I guess I want to be able to have a URL mydomain.com/foobar which will list them all. No categories involved. And with a template file in PHP which I can entirely customise.

Rather than edit the earlier question I have left it there in case the answers there are useful and applicable should someone need a "page without a page". But [cybmeta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/37428/cybmeta) is right, in the comments on that question, all I need in my case is an archive page.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks again to cybmeta for his comments in [my earlier question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173797/can-we-have-a-php-page-without-a-wordpress-page).

Of course the solution is to use an archive template. The filename will be `archive-foobar.php`. The target URL will indeed be `mydomain.com/foobar`.

This works fine, even though for my purposes "archive" is a misnomer. The end user never sees the word "archive".

Additionally, using the [notes here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-archive-page-404s-and-i-dont-know-why), I needed to remember to:

> 1) If you want to use a custom archive page for your custom-post-type, add an additional argument to your
>   register_post_type() arguments: 'has_archive' => true...
>
> (This will tell WP to look for an archive template according to the
>   codex template hierarchy using the current slug setting of your custom
>   post type. If you want a custom slug for your archives, replace TRUE
>   with the slug name for example: 'has_archive' => 'products' might be
>   the slug you want to use with a 'product' post_type.)
>
> 2) Visit the Settings -> Permalinks page to flush your current rewrite rules and rebuild with the new rules for your custom archive.

Comment: I'm glad to help. I would add the use of [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook if you need to modify the list of post in the acrhive page instead of using a custom query or custom loop in the template file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
<?php $args = array('post_type'=>'your-post-type','post_status'=>'publish','posts_per_page'=>9999)
      $query = new Query($args);

if($query->have_posts){
    while($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();
        //Do whatever display you want here
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your function.php, I Never test this but I believe it should solve the problem for you. One thing you needed to do while making use of the code is to change the `custom-post-type1...` to the name of your own CPT.

```
function add_my_CPT( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'nav_menu_item', 'custom-post-type1', 'custom-post-type2', 'custom-post-type2'));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_CPT' );
```